# ¿Cómo ajustar nav de paginador - bootstrap 4 para pantalla de celular?

Tags: php, css, laravel, paginación

estoy intentando mostrar el menú de paginación en mi vista para celular, el contenido no se ajusta al tamaño de la tabla, estoy trabajando con laravel 8.

actualmente luce así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El paginador lo tengo dentro de la tabla, ya probé metiendo el nav en un div, entiendo que por default paginator de bootstrap 4 trae configurados sus estilos, este codigo lo edite desde la carpeta de vendor:

```html
@if ($paginator->hasPages())

<div class="row" id="menu_collapse">
  <nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
      {{-- Previous Page Link --}} @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
      <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
      </li>
      @else
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</a>
      </li>
      @endif {{-- Pagination Elements --}} @foreach ($elements as $element) {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}} @if (is_string($element))
      <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span class="page-link">{{ $element }}</span></li>
      @endif {{-- Array Of Links --}} @if (is_array($element)) @foreach ($element as $page => $url) @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
      <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">{{ $page }}</span></li>
      @else
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
      @endif @endforeach @endif @endforeach {{-- Next Page Link --}} @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
      <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</a>
      </li>
      @else
      <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
        <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
      </li>
      @endif
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>

@endif
```

Al igual estoy probando con css el posicionarlo, seguí una sugerencia que encontré donde decía que pusiera un id al div y le diera posición absoluta pero el menu que manejaban no era paginacion, mas bien era menu lateral.

```css
  @media ( max-width: 30em) {

.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  align-items: right; 
  padding: 1em;
}

#menu_collapse {
  position:absolute;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
}

}
```

esta es mi tabla:

```html
<main class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-12 col-xxl-12 d-flex">
        <div class="card flex-fill">
          <!-- table -->
          <table class="table table-hover my-0 tableClienteIndex" id="dataTable-1">
            <form action="">
              @csrf
              <div class="form-row align-items-right buttonSearchFiltro">
                <div class="col-6 my-0">
                  <input type="search" id="q" name="search" class="form-control m-lg-1" style="font-size: 12px;" placeholder="Escribe aqui...">
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto my-1">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-lg-1" style="font-size: 12px;">Buscar</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>

            <strong>   {{ $clientes->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4') }}</strong>

            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th hidden="">#</th>
                <th id="razonSocialTH">{{ __('Razon social') }}</th>
                <th id="RFCTH">{{ __('RFC') }}</th>
                <th class="ocultarTHTD">{{ __('E-mail de facturación') }}</th>
                <th class="ocultarTHTD">{{ __('Telefono') }}</th>
                @can('admin.clientes.update')
                <th id="accTH">{{ __('Acciones') }}</th>
                @endcan
              </tr>
            </thead>
            @if(count($clientes)) @if($search)
            <h6>
              <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                Los resultados para tu busqueda '{{ $search }}' son:
              </div>
            </h6>
            @endif @foreach ($clientes as $c)
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td hidden="">{{ $c->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $c->razonSocial }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('admin.clientes.show', $c) }}">{{ $c->RFC }}</a></td>
                <td class="ocultarTHTD">{{ $c->emailFacturacion }}</td>
                <td class="ocultarTHTD">{{ $c->telefono }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            @endforeach @else
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
              <strong>No se encontraron resultados para tu busqueda '{{ $search }}'</strong>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
            </div>
            @endif
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>



</main>
```

Comment: Estás buscando que sean menos páginas en móvil o te bastaría con ponerle un overflow-x: scroll ?

Comment: Hola, busco que muestre menos paginas en móvil pero que se puedan consultar las demás al dar click en siguiente >

Answer (score 0):

Estandariza tu código con algo por el estilo

Con la propiedad agent, esto es un ejemplo

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        @if($data->lastPage() > 4 && agent()->isDesktop())
            {{ $data->links() }}
        @else
            {{-- Muestra solo 4 botones si el paginador tiene más de 4 páginas --}}
            @if($data->lastPage() > 4)
                @if($data->currentPage() <= 2)
                    @for($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
                        <li class="page-item {{ $data->currentPage() == $i ? 'active' : '' }}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{{ $data->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endfor
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
                @elseif($data->currentPage() > $data->lastPage() - 2)
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
                    @for($i = $data->lastPage() - 3; $i <= $data->lastPage(); $i++)
                        <li class="page-item {{ $data->currentPage() == $i ? 'active' : '' }}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{{ $data->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endfor
                @else
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
                    @for($i = $data->currentPage() - 1; $i <= $data->currentPage() + 2; $i++)
                        <li class="page-item {{ $data->currentPage() == $i ? 'active' : '' }}">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{{ $data->url($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endfor
                    <li class="page-item disabled"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
                @endif
            @else
                {{-- Muestra todos los botones si el paginador tiene 4 o menos páginas --}}
                {{ $data->links() }}
            @endif
        @endif
    </ul>
</nav>
```